# Proof multivariate normal distribution

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, covariance-matrix, multivariate-normal-distribution

**Definition**: A random vector $X$ has a (multivariate) normal distribution if for every real vector $a$, the random variable $a^TX$ is normal.

**Theorem**: If $X$ has p-variant normal distribution then $\mu=E(X)$ and $\Sigma=Cov(X)$ exist and the distribution is determined by these.

*Someone has the proof of this theorem?*

Comment: I''m assuming this is a homework problem, so I'll provide a hint and ask you to also add the `self-study` tag to your question.  HINT:  Take a look at the uniqueness theorem of Moment Generating Functions.  

Also the above "Definition" is not always true.  It is only true when $a^T$ and $X$ are conformable.

Comment: Yes, the correct definition is: "The $m\times 1$ random vector  is said to have an $m$-variate normal distribution if, for every $a\in\mathbb{R}^m$, the distribution of $a^TX$ is normal.". This is Definition 1.2.3 in Roob J. Muirhead, _Aspects of multivariate Statistical Theory_, where you can find the proof you are looking for (which depends on other results.)

Comment: Hint: set $a=e_1,$ then $a=e_2,$ etc., where $e_i$ is the $i^\text{th}$ standard basis vector.  That immediately gives the first result about $\mu.$  Then consider how to extend this idea to the covariance.  One way is to notice that it suffices to show the variance of each $e_i^\prime X$ is finite.